# How does Mono for Android work and what's the relation between C# and Dalvik?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, dalvik

I'm trying to find some information on how the C# implementation of Android actually works.

Is it C# -> Java -> Bytecode -> Dalvik:
i.e. does C# get converted to Java before the process happens between Bytecode and Dalvik?

Or is it C# -> Dalvik?

Answer (score 4):

Your guess is wrong. It is more similar to .NET/COM interop where wrappers are used across the boundary. So at runtime there are two VMs, Dalvik and Mono CLR running at the same time,

[image: Mono for Android]
<sub>(source: [tirania.org](http://tirania.org/pictures/android-dalvik-mono.png))</sub>

There is a lot more information you can dig up from Miguel's blog such as http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Apr-06.html

The C# to Dalvik solutions do exist, such as [dot42](https://web.archive.org/web/20171028221538/http://dot42.com:80/) and [RemObjects C#](https://www.elementscompiler.com/elements/hydrogene/default.aspx).